# appending generators to a stack in loop, generators point to final loop variable

Tags: python, scope, generator, pass-by-reference

I'm doing some graph traversal. At each point I save a generator of the other possible options that could have been explored. Later, I explore a few of those generators but it doesn't work.

Here is a simplified example where you can see the "node" variable is set to 3 in all the generators. (so the generators point back to the "node" variable, but the "node" variable changes before the generator is consumed.

In my particular case I can store some pointers and add logic of what to do with those pointers to re create the generator - but this is an ugly solution.

Is there a simple way to do it?

```
node_size = {1:1, 2:2, 3:1, 4:3}
iters = []
for node in range(1,4):
    it = (1 + node_size[node]+j for j in xrange(3))
    #it = iter(list(it)) #remove comment to get correct result but very slow.
    iters.append(it)

for iter_ in iters:
    print list(iter_)

"""
Correct Output
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4]
"""

"""
Actual Output:
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
"""
```

Comment: My current best solution is to use itertools.repeat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your generator expression references the global variable `node`.  Since this is a free variable in the genexp, it closes over the *name*, not the value.  Every time you grab an item from the generator, the expression `1 + node_size[node]+j` is evaluated with the *current* value of `node`.  That is, the value of `node` is read each time the generator is advanced, not once and for all at the time it is created.  By the time you start grabbing items from the generator, `node` is 3, so all items in the generator reflect that value.

To get what you want, you need to bind `node` in the generator function itself.  One quick way to do this is to force `node` into the loop portion of the genexp:

```
it = (1 + node_size[node]+j for node in [node] for j in xrange(3))
```

Since the loop part is evaluated just once when the genexp is created, this fixes a single value of `node` in the genexp scope.

If that way is too ugly-looking for you, you will have to write an explicit generator function instead of using a genexp:

```
def gen(nodeVal):
    for j in xrange(3):
        yield 1 + node_size[nodeVal]+j
for node in range(1, 4):
    iters.append(gen(node))
```

Here the generator closes over the name `nodeVal`, but since each generator is created by a separate function call, each gets its own value of `nodeVal` and all is well.

Comment: It's working: explore = ((s - E, e, v) for pos, E, c in [(pos, E, children)] for s, e, v in (c[i] for i in xrange(pos, len(c))))

Answer (score 1):

How about making generator functions that close over the node size value?

```
node_size = {1:1, 2:2, 3:1, 4:3}

iters = []
for node in xrange(1, 4):
    def it(n=node_size[node]):
        for j in xrange(1, 4):
            yield n + j
    itr = it()
    iters.append(itr)

for iter_ in iters:
    print list(iter_)
```

This prints the correct result for me.

EDIT: @BrenBarn posted an answer that led me directly to this answer:

```
node_size = {1:1, 2:2, 3:1, 4:3}

iters = []
for node in range(1, 4):
    n = node_size[node]
    itr = xrange(n+1, n+4)
    iters.append(itr)

for iter_ in iters:
    print list(iter_)
```

When you call `xrange()` it evaluates its arguments and then it gives you back an iterator that yields up the numbers.

I don't think there is any more efficient way to do this in Python!

In this case, we were able to avoid all math and get `xrange()` to yield up exactly the desired numbers.  If you really needed to evaluate an expression you can still do the generator expression way:

```
itr = (1+j for j in xrange(n, n+3))
```